# Is exist flutter component like photo as below?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I need this component like image
Is anyone help me?

[image: component screenhot]

Comment: which one kindly circle it

Comment: I'm pretty sure this image can be created as a Flutter app. However, it takes some effort. If you are on it trying your best and you need help with a *specific* problem, feel free to ask about it. If you need help implementing *all* of it, you may want to hire a professional software developer.

Comment: It's a bottom sheet component you can check modeBottomSheet and bottomSheet in Scaffold